# large number of big decimal type is null when query it

Tags: apache-spark

I have a simple spark code as follows that I want query large number of big decimal type

```
 test("SparkTest 0458") {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("SparkTest0456").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val data =
    (
      new java.math.BigDecimal("819021675302547012738064321"),
      new java.math.BigDecimal("819021675302547012738064321"),
      new java.math.BigDecimal("819021675302547012738064321")
    )

    val df = spark.createDataset(Seq(data)).toDF("a", "b", "c")
    df.show(truncate = false)
  }
```

But it shows 3 nulls

```
+----+----+----+
|a   |b   |c   |
+----+----+----+
|null|null|null|
+----+----+----+
```

I would ask what's wrong here, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the problem is the schema inference mechanism for decimal types. Since neither scale nor precision is part of the type signature, Spark assumes that input is `decimal(38, 18)`:

```
df.printSchema
```

```
root
 |-- a: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
 |-- b: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
 |-- c: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
```

This means that you can store at most 20 digits before decimal point, and the numbers you use, have 26 digits.

As far as I know there is no workaround that works directly with reflection, but it is possible to convert data to `Row` objects and provide schema explicitly. For example with intermediate `RDD`

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import java.math.BigDecimal

val schema = StructType(
  Seq("a", "b", "c") map (c => StructField(c, DecimalType(38, 0)))
)

spark.createDataFrame(
  sc.parallelize(Seq(data)) map(t => Row(t.productIterator.toSeq: _*)),
  schema
)
```

or Kryo-serialized dataset

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder

spark.createDataset(Seq(data))(
  Encoders.kryo: Encoder[(BigDecimal, BigDecimal, BigDecimal)]
).map(t => Row(t.productIterator.toSeq: _*))(RowEncoder(schema))
```